# C# configuring TCPClient client's port

Tags: c#, .net, port, tcpclient, tcp

I have coded `TCPClient()` in `C#` to communicate with another device on LAN. I only have to specify the target IP and port number.

Now I am coding something quite similar to it. However, it specifies that the client port from my PC has to be something greater than `1024`. How can I configure that? does this mean that VS automatically takes care of that if not specified?

Comment: No. The OS assigns the ephemeral port, not Visual Studio. But it's always greater than 1024, so don't worry.

Comment: is there any way that I can specify the client port myself?

Comment: Yes, if you use a `Socket` and you call `Bind`. But what's the point? It will be greater than 1024 automatically.

Comment: I am just curious.  The document from which I got the specs does not tell me that the OS takes care of the client port assignment, only that it has to be greater than 1024.  So, I wonder if client port assignment by user is possible.

Comment: thanks harold, that answers everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TcpClient(IPEndPoint)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f.aspx) can be used to specify the client port (just use `IPAddress.Any` for the address part). As documented on [Socket.Bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx) and [wikipedia:ephemeral_port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port), by default a port higher than 1024 would be used.